# tkinter - how to resize frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create simple gui in tkinter that consist of notebook frame and several frames inside of each tabs. Let's say I want 2 labeled frames inside each of notebook's tabs spanning 100% of window width and 50% of window height.

[Screen layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptODF.png)

I will have more frames/elements inside that I want to take x% of the window widht/height.

I read that tkinter gui should resize automatically when window is resized, but I cannot get it to work.

1. How do I set frames to take 100% of window width and (for example) 50% of window height?
2. How do I center the frame so it is not stick to left-upper corner?

I cannot figure out how to do it with grid layout manager and documentation says it should be used over pack.

Example of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.title("Test")

tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_frame.grid()

####### change Notebook size in case main window changes
def conf(event):
    tab_frame.config(height=root.winfo_height(), width=root.winfo_width())
    # without this you cannot resize frames of the notebook by grid(sticky) or width/height !
    return
    
root.bind("<Configure>",conf)
#######

s1 = ttk.Style()
s1.configure('test_red.TFrame', background='red')
s2 = ttk.Style()
s2.configure('test_green.TFrame', background='green')
s3 = ttk.Style()
s3.configure('test_blue.TFrame', background='blue')


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, height=100, width=100, style='test_red.TFrame')
tab1.grid()
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, height=100, width=100, style='test_blue.TFrame')
tab2.grid()

tab_frame.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
tab_frame.add(tab2, text='Tab2')

### frames in tab
label_frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label1', width=100, height=100, style='test_green.TFrame')
label_frame1.grid()
#label_frame.grid(sticky='e') # sticky does not work in any combination

label_frame2 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label2', width=100, height=100, style='test_blue.TFrame')
label_frame2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using: `tab1.pack(fill="x")`, `tab2.pack(fill="both")`, `label_frame1.pack(fill="x")`, and `label_frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)` instead of the `.grid()`s. Then you can adjust the `height` of `label_frame1`. What documentation says that `.grid()` should be used over `.pack()`? Both have their advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can use `tab_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)` instead of `.grid()` and then you don't need to bind `<Configure>` event to resize `tab_frame`.

Second you can use `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()` to make the two `LabelFrame`s to fill horizontally and vertically.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.title("Test")

tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1) # used pack() instead of grid()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('test_red.TFrame', background='red')
s.configure('test_green.TFrame', background='green')
s.configure('test_blue.TFrame', background='blue')

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, style='test_red.TFrame')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, style='test_blue.TFrame')

tab_frame.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
tab_frame.add(tab2, text='Tab2')

# make two LabelFrames to fill horizontally
tab1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# make two LabelFrames to evenly fill vertically
tab1.rowconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

### frames in tab
label_frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label1', style='test_green.TFrame')
label_frame1.grid(sticky="nsew")

label_frame2 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label2', style='test_blue.TFrame')
label_frame2.grid(sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

You can use `place()` on the two LabelFrames to achieve same goal:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.title("Test")

tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1) # used pack() instead of grid()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('test_red.TFrame', background='red')
s.configure('test_green.TFrame', background='green')
s.configure('test_blue.TFrame', background='blue')

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, style='test_red.TFrame')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, style='test_blue.TFrame')

tab_frame.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
tab_frame.add(tab2, text='Tab2')

### frames in tab
label_frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label1', style='test_green.TFrame')
label_frame1.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)

label_frame2 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label2', style='test_blue.TFrame')
label_frame2.place(x=0, rely=0.5, relwidth=1, relheight=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified resizable Notebook with two `labelframes` each containing a `button`.

The problem you are having is due to the grid manager default not being resizable, unlike other managers.

The solution is to use function `flexx`.

`flexx` is a necessary function that makes grid objects flexible.

`flexx` is always applied to containers like `labelframes`, `frames` and the `root` or `master` widget

`grid` is a convenience function

You should be able to populate each `notebook` tab with any number of widgets.

The thing to remember is containers like `labelframe` must contain some widget to exist.

Applying `flexx` to the `root` is essential in order to make `Tk` or '`Toplevel` window flexible.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

def flexx( o, r = 0, c = 0, rw = 1, cw = 1 ):
    '''flexx will control grid manager static|dymanic growth'''
    if r != None:
        o.rowconfigure( r, weight = rw )
    if c != None:
        o.columnconfigure( c, weight = cw )

def grid( r = 0, c = 0, s = 'nsew', rs = 1, cs = 1 ) ->'Grid manager settings':
    '''grid( r = 0, c = 0, s = nsew, rs = 1, cs = 1 )'''
    return dict( row=r, column=c, rowspan=rs, columnspan=cs, sticky=s )


root = Tk()
root.geometry('568x427')
root.title("Test")
flexx( root ) # essential for other objects to resize

tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_frame.grid( grid() )

def closer( ev = None ):
    root.destroy( )

root.bind( '<Escape>', closer )

s1 = ttk.Style()
s1.configure('test_red.TFrame', background='red')
s2 = ttk.Style()
s2.configure('test_green.TFrame', background='green')
s3 = ttk.Style()
s3.configure('test_blue.TFrame', background='blue')

# Tab1 objects
label_frame1 = ttk.Labelframe( tab_frame, labelanchor= 'n', text='Label1', style='test_green.TFrame')
label_frame1.grid( grid( ) )
flexx( label_frame1 )
tk.Button( label_frame1, text = 'button_1' ).grid( grid() )
tab_frame.add(label_frame1, text='Tab1')
tk.Button( label_frame1, text = 'button_2' ).grid( grid(r=1) )
flexx( label_frame1, r=1 )

# Tab2 objects
label_frame2 = ttk.Labelframe( tab_frame, labelanchor= 'n', text='Label2', style='test_blue.TFrame')
label_frame2.grid( grid( ) )
flexx( label_frame2 )
tk.Button( label_frame2, text = 'button_3' ).grid( grid() )
tab_frame.add(label_frame2, text='Tab1')
tk.Button( label_frame2, text = 'button_4' ).grid( grid(r=1) )
flexx( label_frame2, r=1 )
tab_frame.add(label_frame2, text='Tab2')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just following @TheLizzard's comment and writing answer.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.title("Test")

tab_frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab_frame.grid()

def conf(event):
    tab_frame.config(height=root.winfo_height(), width=root.winfo_width())
    return
    
root.bind("<Configure>",conf)

s1 = ttk.Style()
s1.configure('test_red.TFrame', background='red')
s2 = ttk.Style()
s2.configure('test_green.TFrame', background='green')
s3 = ttk.Style()
s3.configure('test_blue.TFrame', background='blue')


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, height=100, width=100, style='test_red.TFrame')
tab1.pack(fill="x")
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_frame, height=100, width=100, style='test_blue.TFrame')
tab2.pack(fill="both")

tab_frame.add(tab1, text='Tab1')
tab_frame.add(tab2, text='Tab2')

label_frame1 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label1', width=100, height=100, style='test_green.TFrame')
label_frame1.pack(fill="x")

label_frame2 = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text='Label2', width=100, height=100, style='test_blue.TFrame')
label_frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

If this solve your problem then mark this as answer!